# Jetty: CONNECTOR_SELECT_CHANNEL cannot be resolved

Tags: java, jetty

The compiler tells me that CONNECTOR_SELECT_CHANNEL cannot be resolved or is not a field, at the following code line 
client.setConnectorType(HttpClient.CONNECTOR_SELECT_CHANNEL);

I can't find where this CONNECTOR_SELECT_CHANNEL is located and what i should import (or what JAR should i add to the project)

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same problem and the solution I figured out is to use another version of Jetty. The current latest (v9.2.6) was giving me the same error what's in the title above.
Then I download jetty v8.1.16 and added in Eclipse (JUNO) to the "Java Build Path -> Libraries" (instead of v9.2.6) and the problem was resolved. 
Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

This is present in jetty-client jar.

It is present in v6.1.9 and above, I do not know about previous versions.